# How can i get shape keys from a animation with keyframes?

Tags: shape-keys

I hope this is not a dumb question. I am a newbie and im not sure if this is proper. How can i make shape keys from a animation with keyframes? how can that be accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to apply an armature modifier as a shape key. Be aware that you will end up with an undeformed starting point and a deformed end point: the mid locations of every single vertex will be in the center of the straight line connecting start point and end point, this often leads to unpleasant results.

[image]

Comment: I really appreciate your time helping me out. I loved the suggestion!!!! A million thanks